# Add automatic code analysis to legacy or already started code base

Tags: .net, code-analysis, conventions, stylecop, legacy-code

I am trying to figure out some elegant and effective ways of integrating a code analysis tool (such as StyleCop) to existing code. It's about an ongoing project (.NET, c#), which has been started 2 years ago. I suppose I can interpret it as a legacy basis, written from many developers, everybody following his/her own coding standards and conventions.

Initially, I wanted to introduce such standards by writing them down in a wiki, but then I decided that StyleCop will do a much better job, by applying those rules and also warns the developer when violating them.

Here comes the problem with the thousands of warnings of the current codebase.

And what I am thinking is implementing this process in steps:

- Setup StyleCop for just one project as a start (and for every new project which is going to be created, of course).
- Tweak the rules and leave only the important (for me and the team) ones -> kind of a subjective point.
- Treat all violations as Warnings.
- Clean the warnings step-by-step, with every task, which is related to the files of interest -> to preserve the chosen work methodology the team is working with.

I'll appreciate any guidance, ideas, and details you can think of or which you have experienced so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Feels like a question you need to ask your team: they will need to be onboard for this to be worthwhile.

I would probably start in a light-handed:

- Stylecop should give warnings.
- Developers are expected to fix warnings in the files they touch.
- Reviewers should consider whether this has been done.

I have always implemented coding standards as part of the Code Review process.